# Loop over the indices of a slice

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the `__getitem__` method for a class in python. I want to try something like...

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
  if isinstance(key, int):
    return foo(key)
  elif isinstance(key, slice):
    return [foo(k) for k in key]
  else:
    raise TypeError("Invalid index.")
```

...but I get a `'slice' object is not iterable` error whenever I actually try to use it with a slice. What's the correct way to do this in python?

Comment: I'm not sure showing any other code would be useful. Basically, what I want is to take a slice that's from say n to m and loop over the values n to m, just as I can loop over range(n, m).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`indices()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) method of the slice, and pass the results to `range()` or `xrange()`.

```
>>> slice(2, 5).indices(7)
(2, 5, 1)
>>> range(*slice(2, 5).indices(7))
[2, 3, 4]
>>> range(*slice(2, 10).indices(7))
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The reason this is by far the best approach is that `indices` will handle negative, default (`None`) and out of bounds slice indexes properly for you. It is very easy to get it wrong in some cases if you try to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Indices may work but you could also just use the start, stop and step of the slice, although they can be empty so you need to do something like this...

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
  if isinstance(key, int):
    return foo(key)
  elif isinstance(key, slice):
    start = key.start if key.start is not None else 0
    stop = key.stop
    step = key.step if key.step is not None else 1
    return [foo(k) for k in range(start, stop, step)]
  else:
    raise TypeError("Invalid index.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'd run into here is that as the exception says: a `slice` object isn't iterable.  I find the best way to think of a slice is that it's an instruction that is given to an iterable to determine what it returns.  So if you're trying to get something like this:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L[1:3]
[2, 3]
```

(obviously this is a simplified example using lists instead of a custom class)

The slice that is handed to `__getitem__` will have a few attributes you can use:

```
>>> s = slice(1, 2, 3)
>>> s.start, s.stop, s.step
```

(1, 2, 3)

If you say `s = slice(1, 2)` then the `step` attribute will be `None`.  You can use this information to get a slice of a list, tuple or whatever you want in `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    if isinstance(i, int):
        return foo(i)
    elif isinstance(i, slice):
        return [foo(k) for k in self.bar[i]]  # where bar is a list/tuple
```

The reason this works is because calling `self.bar[i]` where `i` is a slice is really no different to calling `self.bar[1:2]`, because the `1:2` is simply a `slice` object as is `i`.

Hope this was helpful!